# Sorting every row in dataframe based on first row python dataframe

Tags: python, excel, dataframe

I would like to sort every row of data frame based on data in first row. 
For example:
The input data frame is

[image]

The output should be:

[image]

I tried looking for sort function but I somehow could not achieve the output shared above.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer to the above question which is :
df.apply(lambda x: sorted(x.values), axis=1)

It will sort all the values from all the rows.